# How to remove domain name from this variable?

Tags: javascript

How to remove domain name from this variable?
var s="DOMAIN\stimothy"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: s= replace("DOMAIN\", "")

Comment: @user3227295 Shouldn't it be `s=s.replace("DOMAIN", "SomethingElse");`

Answer (score 0):

Try split and get the last element:

```
var s="DOMAIN\\stimothy";
s=s.split('\\')[1]

alert(s);
```

Comment: If you're going for a split method, this is more effective as it overwrites the old string with the split string *As asked in the question* `s=s.split('\\')[1];`

Comment: @NewToJS. Yes you are correct. Thanks, I have updated the answer to reflect this.